# Why am I getting a TypeError with my nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, typeerror

The goal of my code is to simulate a very primitive bank by reading banking actions from a text file. I successfully made the program using lists to store the information, but then figured I could redo it using nested dictionaries to remove the need for iteration through the lists.

```
commands = open('textfile.txt', 'r')
commands_line = commands.readlines()
transactions = {}
dates = []
accountinfo = {}
p = 0
class StoreInfo:
    def apply(name, email, number, type):
        accountinfo[name]["name"] = name
        accountinfo[name]["email"] = email
        accountinfo[name]["number"] = number
        accountinfo[name]["type"] = type
        accountinfo[name]["balance"] = 0
        return
class deposit:
    def apply(name, money, date):
        accountinfo[name]["balance"] += int(money.replace('\n',''))
        transactions[name]["transaction"+str(p)] = date + ',' + money.replace('\n', '') + ',$' + (accountinfo[name]["balance"])
        p+=1
class withdraw:
    def apply(name, money, date):
        accountinfo[name]["balance"] -= int(money.replace('\n',''))
        transactions[name]["transaction"+str(p)] = date.replace('\n','') + ',' + str(int(money)*-1) + ',$' + str(accountinfo[name]["balance"])
        p+=1
class balinquery:
    def apply(name):
        print(account[name]["balance"])
class accountinfo:
    def apply(name):
        n=0
        all = transactions[name].values()
        while n < len(all):
            print(all[n])
            n+=1
class bank:
    def apply():
        i = 0
        while i < sum(1 for line in open('textfile.txt')):
            readcommand = commands_line[i].split(',')
            if(readcommand[1] == 'CREATE'):
                StoreInfo.apply(readcommand[2], readcommand[4], readcommand[5], type)
            elif(readcommand[1] == 'DEPOSIT'):
                deposit.apply(readcommand[2], readcommand[4], readcommand[0])
            elif(readcommand[1] == 'WITHDRAW'):
                withdraw.apply(readcommand[2], readcommand[4], readcommand[0])
            elif(readcommand[1] == 'BAL-INQUERY'):
                balinquery.apply(readcommand[2])
            elif(readcommand[1] == 'ACCOUNT-INFO'):
                accountinfo.apply(readcommand[2])
            i += 1
bank.apply()
```

For some reason I get a `TypeError: type is not subscriptable` error everytime I try to add/change a value for my nested dictionary. Why is this happening?

EDIT: Here's the content of the text file

```
2020-07-20,CREATE,Aaren,SAVINGS,5859469480,ooyqb@gmail.com
2020-07-21,CREATE,Aarika,SAVINGS,3056693828,wmtsv@gmail.com
2020-07-22,CREATE,Abagael,SAVINGS,3133519185,pxbvo@gmail.com
2020-07-23,CREATE,Abagail,SAVINGS,1291985910,srjnj@gmail.com
2020-07-24,CREATE,Abbe,SAVINGS,3935194484,fupnj@gmail.com
2020-07-25,CREATE,Abbey,SAVINGS,6050058379,ogjsw@gmail.com
2020-07-26,CREATE,Abbi,SAVINGS,7843610633,dslyp@gmail.com
2020-07-27,CREATE,Abbie,SAVINGS,1023801257,ohkte@gmail.com
2020-07-28,CREATE,Abby,SAVINGS,3106403957,bmlnz@gmail.com
2020-07-29,CREATE,Abbye,SAVINGS,5790123218,jzpzg@gmail.com
2020-07-30,CREATE,Abigael,SAVINGS,9026786275,gkjqb@gmail.com
2020-07-31,CREATE,Abigail,SAVINGS,1504576581,ojcjr@gmail.com
2020-08-01,CREATE,Abigale,SAVINGS,1351609338,jgshy@gmail.com
2020-08-02,CREATE,Abra,SAVINGS,3007400093,juzrp@gmail.com
2020-08-03,CREATE,Ada,SAVINGS,4647156053,xjblc@gmail.com
2020-08-04,CREATE,Adah,SAVINGS,3508419019,qbftx@gmail.com
2020-08-05,CREATE,Adaline,SAVINGS,6888096958,ncknp@gmail.com
2020-08-06,CREATE,Adan,SAVINGS,5533481588,byyss@gmail.com
2020-08-07,CREATE,Adara,SAVINGS,4398536077,tmkcd@gmail.com
2020-08-08,CREATE,Adda,SAVINGS,5244094037,psjks@gmail.com
2020-08-09,CREATE,Addi,SAVINGS,4452856504,qswoj@gmail.com
2020-08-10,CREATE,Addia,SAVINGS,5302894886,xqmzo@gmail.com
2020-08-11,CREATE,Addie,SAVINGS,1128152010,suufx@gmail.com
2020-08-12,CREATE,Addy,SAVINGS,3577576322,vdngs@gmail.com
2020-08-13,CREATE,Adel,SAVINGS,7502004323,umjco@gmail.com
2020-08-14,CREATE,Adela,SAVINGS,3613096589,qukvw@gmail.com
2020-08-15,CREATE,Adelaida,SAVINGS,3982934387,irnxz@gmail.com
2020-08-16,CREATE,Adelaide,SAVINGS,1382692057,hzuro@gmail.com
2020-08-17,CREATE,Adele,SAVINGS,7753417526,isesp@gmail.com
2020-08-18,CREATE,Adelheid,SAVINGS,8366272045,rhmeb@gmail.com
2020-08-19,CREATE,Adelice,SAVINGS,2976782369,uhsne@gmail.com
2020-08-20,CREATE,Adelina,SAVINGS,8911778657,iduhy@gmail.com
2020-08-21,CREATE,Adelind,SAVINGS,6102163265,scsvz@gmail.com
2020-08-22,CREATE,Adeline,SAVINGS,9419849982,nguwt@gmail.com
2020-08-23,CREATE,Adella,SAVINGS,1991436866,wczjo@gmail.com
2020-08-24,CREATE,Adelle,SAVINGS,6694547867,dooph@gmail.com
2020-08-25,CREATE,Adena,SAVINGS,2929774725,cknfr@gmail.com
2020-08-26,CREATE,Adey,SAVINGS,3265351514,wxmvh@gmail.com
2020-08-27,CREATE,Adi,SAVINGS,5324295973,kryus@gmail.com
2020-08-28,CREATE,Adiana,SAVINGS,6126290865,mvgpl@gmail.com
2020-08-29,CREATE,Adina,SAVINGS,4711332664,rvhjz@gmail.com
2020-08-30,CREATE,Adora,SAVINGS,2648113695,bqmkm@gmail.com
2020-08-31,CREATE,Adore,SAVINGS,4775721242,bfhwe@gmail.com
2020-09-01,CREATE,Adoree,SAVINGS,8650468812,lnvue@gmail.com
2020-09-02,CREATE,Adorne,SAVINGS,9529186786,nnjhh@gmail.com
2020-09-03,CREATE,Adrea,SAVINGS,9351172139,ndxlz@gmail.com
2020-09-04,CREATE,Adria,SAVINGS,7995215960,upszu@gmail.com
2020-09-05,CREATE,Adriaens,SAVINGS,4539458489,gbfxj@gmail.com
2020-09-06,CREATE,Adrian,SAVINGS,6223393775,wekrh@gmail.com
2020-09-07,CREATE,Adriana,SAVINGS,9687498870,iybcy@gmail.com
2020-09-08,CREATE,Adriane,SAVINGS,9580929004,lwwrn@gmail.com
2020-09-09,CREATE,Adrianna,SAVINGS,4287796855,ufnbz@gmail.com
2020-09-10,CREATE,Adrianne,SAVINGS,3938555477,xbnkj@gmail.com
2020-09-11,CREATE,Adriena,SAVINGS,4759607688,rolvn@gmail.com
2020-09-12,CREATE,Adrienne,SAVINGS,7615621449,ooicp@gmail.com
2020-09-13,CREATE,Aeriel,SAVINGS,1482849560,khevw@gmail.com
2020-09-14,CREATE,Aeriela,SAVINGS,7068693388,pbpxb@gmail.com
2020-09-15,CREATE,Aeriell,SAVINGS,9245985639,woojb@gmail.com
2020-09-16,CREATE,Afton,SAVINGS,5345744601,hycro@gmail.com
2020-09-17,CREATE,Ag,SAVINGS,7635647183,kqrnw@gmail.com
2020-09-18,CREATE,Agace,SAVINGS,5119703239,xkjwy@gmail.com
2020-09-19,CREATE,Agata,SAVINGS,9400247408,beytx@gmail.com
2020-09-20,CREATE,Agatha,SAVINGS,6292235670,zlgxj@gmail.com
2020-09-21,CREATE,Agathe,SAVINGS,9555299310,nlfem@gmail.com
2020-09-22,CREATE,Aggi,SAVINGS,8616752864,hijqd@gmail.com
2020-09-23,CREATE,Aggie,SAVINGS,7985039581,xtpkf@gmail.com
2020-09-24,CREATE,Aggy,SAVINGS,3382681292,gcooz@gmail.com
2020-09-25,CREATE,Agna,SAVINGS,7834981484,tkzmv@gmail.com
2020-09-26,CREATE,Agnella,SAVINGS,3307916452,tdolm@gmail.com
2020-09-27,CREATE,Agnes,SAVINGS,5938961208,smzql@gmail.com
2020-09-28,CREATE,Agnese,SAVINGS,2949090191,pnwot@gmail.com
2020-09-29,CREATE,Agnesse,SAVINGS,3432354977,njoik@gmail.com
2020-09-30,CREATE,Agneta,SAVINGS,4998380684,bspue@gmail.com
2020-10-01,CREATE,Agnola,SAVINGS,4834406406,qppmv@gmail.com
2020-10-02,CREATE,Agretha,SAVINGS,8646542712,dfzfx@gmail.com
2020-10-03,CREATE,Aida,CHECKING,1565289449,ntwlu@gmail.com
2020-10-04,CREATE,Aidan,CHECKING,8525130800,rkeww@gmail.com
2020-10-05,CREATE,Aigneis,CHECKING,9882107761,wuepe@gmail.com
2020-10-06,CREATE,Aila,CHECKING,2949967625,jmztm@gmail.com
2020-10-07,CREATE,Aile,CHECKING,1341253914,qbrcx@gmail.com
2020-10-08,CREATE,Ailee,CHECKING,6320257812,rzcrj@gmail.com
2020-10-09,CREATE,Aileen,CHECKING,9467105368,xvrjf@gmail.com
2020-10-10,CREATE,Ailene,CHECKING,4705499230,fqxzo@gmail.com
2020-10-11,CREATE,Ailey,CHECKING,7532118582,wzufu@gmail.com
2020-10-12,CREATE,Aili,CHECKING,3005226433,evhrb@gmail.com
2020-10-13,CREATE,Ailina,CHECKING,6463369208,pxocm@gmail.com
2020-10-14,CREATE,Ailis,CHECKING,8458600856,ymtuy@gmail.com
2020-10-15,CREATE,Ailsun,CHECKING,9638332973,cqcij@gmail.com
2020-10-16,CREATE,Ailyn,CHECKING,7420051069,fxhpq@gmail.com
2020-10-17,CREATE,Aime,CHECKING,5788014979,sjetk@gmail.com
2020-10-18,CREATE,Aimee,CHECKING,8698220764,gkofc@gmail.com
2020-10-19,CREATE,Aimil,CHECKING,7757702512,oyhiz@gmail.com
2020-10-20,CREATE,Aindrea,CHECKING,6917871464,tsqks@gmail.com
2020-10-21,CREATE,Ainslee,CHECKING,1124862153,kbsxk@gmail.com
2020-10-22,CREATE,Ainsley,CHECKING,1944921596,fcbgd@gmail.com
2020-10-23,CREATE,Ainslie,CHECKING,8722144152,btiio@gmail.com
2020-10-24,CREATE,Ajay,CHECKING,2316152423,xlqym@gmail.com
2020-10-25,CREATE,Alaine,CHECKING,2624016818,ninyd@gmail.com
2020-10-26,CREATE,Alameda,CHECKING,8836331042,hernk@gmail.com
2020-10-27,CREATE,Alana,CHECKING,3953943717,uznyh@gmail.com
2020-10-28,CREATE,Alanah,CHECKING,2427372021,hocqb@gmail.com
2020-10-29,CREATE,Alane,CHECKING,9582634381,wmcvg@gmail.com
2020-10-30,CREATE,Alanna,CHECKING,9974930422,phwkq@gmail.com
2020-10-31,CREATE,Alayne,CHECKING,9341305210,khiim@gmail.com
2020-11-01,CREATE,Alberta,CHECKING,9098369441,szuxe@gmail.com
2020-11-02,CREATE,Albertina,CHECKING,3213238968,rsqsz@gmail.com
2020-11-03,CREATE,Albertine,CHECKING,9664181366,tqpnh@gmail.com
2020-11-04,CREATE,Albina,CHECKING,1402203684,imtsr@gmail.com
2020-11-05,CREATE,Alecia,CHECKING,1158740476,otyun@gmail.com
2020-11-06,CREATE,Aleda,CHECKING,2795187505,ocisd@gmail.com
2020-11-07,CREATE,Aleece,CHECKING,2641445088,pbgwo@gmail.com
2020-11-08,CREATE,Aleen,CHECKING,4921614537,csryl@gmail.com
2020-11-09,CREATE,Alejandra,CHECKING,8801343917,cptrw@gmail.com
2020-11-10,CREATE,Alejandrina,CHECKING,1168284989,uisrc@gmail.com
2020-11-11,CREATE,Alena,CHECKING,4751108015,rjffd@gmail.com
2020-11-12,CREATE,Alene,CHECKING,9273055955,jpzig@gmail.com
2020-11-13,CREATE,Alessandra,CHECKING,4237341861,zpnmc@gmail.com
2020-11-14,CREATE,Aleta,CHECKING,9076825377,jnbfc@gmail.com
2020-11-15,CREATE,Alethea,CHECKING,4763631035,gxdmr@gmail.com
2020-11-16,CREATE,Alex,CHECKING,3600441562,pxwij@gmail.com
2020-11-17,CREATE,Alexa,CHECKING,3616788890,qjfno@gmail.com
2020-11-18,CREATE,Alexandra,CHECKING,9689197912,nzdyl@gmail.com
2020-11-19,CREATE,Alexandrina,CHECKING,2092004315,hdfoi@gmail.com
2020-11-20,CREATE,Alexi,CHECKING,5291880895,qjveh@gmail.com
2020-11-21,CREATE,Alexia,CHECKING,5011177582,ikfec@gmail.com
2020-11-22,CREATE,Alexina,CHECKING,4637958316,kelkq@gmail.com
2020-11-23,CREATE,Alexine,CHECKING,9973443063,xsvcg@gmail.com
2020-11-24,CREATE,Alexis,CHECKING,7236445684,spqyh@gmail.com
2020-11-25,CREATE,Alfi,CHECKING,7016577816,bpoxm@gmail.com
2020-11-26,CREATE,Alfie,CHECKING,3917111175,dcrdi@gmail.com
2020-11-27,CREATE,Alfreda,CHECKING,5714862686,setff@gmail.com
2020-11-28,CREATE,Alfy,CHECKING,8121018057,dxrjc@gmail.com
2020-11-29,CREATE,Ali,CHECKING,7563328487,sigob@gmail.com
2020-11-30,CREATE,Alia,CHECKING,1649864800,ygzgn@gmail.com
2020-12-01,CREATE,Alica,CHECKING,6354316641,xmbgk@gmail.com
2020-12-02,CREATE,Alice,CHECKING,5362529953,vsbgx@gmail.com
2020-12-03,CREATE,Alicea,CHECKING,6416924378,kdymg@gmail.com
2020-12-04,CREATE,Alicia,CHECKING,5072456112,nuwhv@gmail.com
2020-12-05,CREATE,Alida,CHECKING,8893587205,zovfp@gmail.com
2020-12-06,CREATE,Alidia,CHECKING,1379265209,izlit@gmail.com
2020-12-07,CREATE,Alie,CHECKING,9196590984,yhtrn@gmail.com
2020-12-08,CREATE,Alika,CHECKING,5456325553,jdptg@gmail.com
2020-12-09,CREATE,Alikee,CHECKING,4204051561,jbyyc@gmail.com
2020-12-10,CREATE,Alina,CHECKING,4840090507,pqbzf@gmail.com
2020-12-11,CREATE,Aline,CHECKING,7993455789,ubhtl@gmail.com
2020-12-12,CREATE,Alis,CHECKING,2685555337,rvzto@gmail.com
2020-12-13,CREATE,Alisa,CHECKING,5680153120,dbkcm@gmail.com
2020-12-14,CREATE,Alisha,CHECKING,4660297686,mpeyt@gmail.com
2020-12-15,CREATE,Alison,CHECKING,4435729868,mvjvk@gmail.com
2020-12-16,CREATE,Alissa,CHECKING,4419301682,nlphv@gmail.com
2020-12-17,CREATE,Alisun,CREDIT,8104412003,tplix@gmail.com
2020-12-18,CREATE,Alix,CREDIT,2102964013,bvecy@gmail.com
2020-12-19,CREATE,Aliza,CREDIT,8634801547,jitxm@gmail.com
2020-12-20,CREATE,Alla,CREDIT,1506207140,xlycc@gmail.com
2020-12-21,CREATE,Alleen,CREDIT,9602760478,hrxtk@gmail.com
2020-12-22,CREATE,Allegra,CREDIT,1058373345,tklum@gmail.com
2020-12-23,CREATE,Allene,CREDIT,5406614554,xjpvq@gmail.com
2020-12-24,CREATE,Alli,CREDIT,2427894074,njswq@gmail.com
2020-12-25,CREATE,Allianora,CREDIT,9549753986,hjdbc@gmail.com
2020-12-26,CREATE,Allie,CREDIT,7036286610,undbp@gmail.com
2020-12-27,CREATE,Allina,CREDIT,9145276354,rbwzg@gmail.com
2020-12-28,CREATE,Allis,CREDIT,2919384541,owzlv@gmail.com
2020-12-29,CREATE,Allison,CREDIT,1715645873,pcqis@gmail.com
2020-12-30,CREATE,Allissa,CREDIT,7165026953,imkmn@gmail.com
2020-12-31,CREATE,Allix,CREDIT,8306285691,uqcbj@gmail.com
2021-01-01,CREATE,Allsun,CREDIT,7027476993,tmeej@gmail.com
2021-01-02,CREATE,Allx,CREDIT,8993080791,tkzup@gmail.com
2021-01-03,CREATE,Ally,CREDIT,9979949053,eclxy@gmail.com
2021-01-04,CREATE,Allyce,CREDIT,6306005657,gcvur@gmail.com
2021-01-05,CREATE,Allyn,CREDIT,8896526413,mrcsv@gmail.com
2021-01-06,CREATE,Allys,CREDIT,3260490839,ngbhg@gmail.com
2021-01-07,CREATE,Allyson,CREDIT,5961461132,hwrby@gmail.com
2021-01-08,CREATE,Alma,CREDIT,8639269332,mtdnt@gmail.com
2021-01-09,CREATE,Almeda,CREDIT,6462184874,reugr@gmail.com
2021-01-10,CREATE,Almeria,CREDIT,9710184800,vcqbp@gmail.com
2021-01-11,CREATE,Almeta,CREDIT,2121495964,dqroc@gmail.com
2021-01-12,CREATE,Almira,CREDIT,6672949693,lnopd@gmail.com
2021-01-13,CREATE,Almire,CREDIT,3610359369,evsjn@gmail.com
2021-01-14,CREATE,Aloise,CREDIT,9827639952,srxbp@gmail.com
2021-01-15,CREATE,Aloisia,CREDIT,5418064525,srqpm@gmail.com
2021-01-16,CREATE,Aloysia,CREDIT,6738443601,zznot@gmail.com
2021-01-17,CREATE,Alta,CREDIT,3901930504,zkhsd@gmail.com
2021-01-18,CREATE,Althea,CREDIT,6943832628,knpmg@gmail.com
2021-01-19,CREATE,Alvera,CREDIT,9395409490,toxxj@gmail.com
2021-01-20,CREATE,Alverta,CREDIT,8935194060,dfpfo@gmail.com
2021-01-21,CREATE,Alvina,CREDIT,4544630846,zzmhj@gmail.com
2021-01-22,CREATE,Alvinia,CREDIT,3067833455,wflxp@gmail.com
2021-01-23,CREATE,Alvira,CREDIT,5289239490,bbwqk@gmail.com
2021-01-24,CREATE,Alyce,CREDIT,6138826839,pvtbh@gmail.com
2021-01-25,CREATE,Alyda,CREDIT,9636364446,xlqsy@gmail.com
2021-01-26,CREATE,Alys,CREDIT,2743825034,keefu@gmail.com
2021-01-27,CREATE,Alysa,CREDIT,2362200689,nuoze@gmail.com
2021-01-28,CREATE,Alyse,CREDIT,2880602621,rilwe@gmail.com
2021-01-29,CREATE,Alysia,CREDIT,1525346145,wevfl@gmail.com
2021-01-30,CREATE,Alyson,CREDIT,6705510938,fspih@gmail.com
2021-01-31,CREATE,Alyss,CREDIT,9042102044,fdzqg@gmail.com
2021-02-01,CREATE,Alyssa,CREDIT,3453520541,epgol@gmail.com
2021-02-02,CREATE,Amabel,CREDIT,2524423619,rzhqn@gmail.com
2021-02-03,CREATE,Amabelle,CREDIT,8403766343,lvwcx@gmail.com
2021-02-04,CREATE,Amalea,CREDIT,8850655637,bzgec@gmail.com
2021-02-05,CREATE,Amalee,CREDIT,3984867735,iiejp@gmail.com
2021-02-06,CREATE,Amaleta,CREDIT,4886140767,kjnnr@gmail.com
2021-02-07,CREATE,Amalia,CREDIT,4554053011,utunk@gmail.com
2021-02-08,CREATE,Amalie,CREDIT,5532123597,nbuiu@gmail.com
2021-02-09,CREATE,Amalita,CREDIT,3153503448,zwdgs@gmail.com
2021-02-10,CREATE,Amalle,CREDIT,6451841262,zmvyz@gmail.com
2021-02-11,CREATE,Amanda,CREDIT,5380417080,gpnyd@gmail.com
2021-02-12,CREATE,Amandi,CREDIT,6228835209,ivoqe@gmail.com
2021-02-13,CREATE,Amandie,CREDIT,9619463525,vywcg@gmail.com
2021-02-14,CREATE,Amandy,CREDIT,9162918944,yzutb@gmail.com
2021-02-15,CREATE,Amara,CREDIT,4182384359,lbcru@gmail.com
2021-02-16,CREATE,Amargo,CREDIT,5791009913,sednu@gmail.com
2021-02-17,CREATE,Amata,CREDIT,1407571815,rrpmf@gmail.com
2021-02-18,CREATE,Amber,CREDIT,2660922152,sbziv@gmail.com
2021-02-19,CREATE,Amberly,CREDIT,9931866270,gdmqb@gmail.com
2021-02-20,CREATE,Ambur,CREDIT,3876454000,pcwtg@gmail.com
2021-02-21,CREATE,Ame,CREDIT,4017965653,wmnho@gmail.com
2021-02-22,CREATE,Amelia,CREDIT,2997015132,ugogm@gmail.com
2021-02-23,CREATE,Amelie,CREDIT,3435153907,qmkzy@gmail.com
2021-02-24,CREATE,Amelina,CREDIT,5057094775,kjytu@gmail.com
2021-02-25,CREATE,Ameline,CREDIT,1967095560,fogyf@gmail.com
2021-02-26,CREATE,Amelita,CREDIT,8930439036,dugcn@gmail.com
2021-02-27,CREATE,Ami,CREDIT,9425147513,lmycx@gmail.com
2021-02-28,CREATE,Amie,CREDIT,8935820788,ypirn@gmail.com
2021-03-01,CREATE,Amii,CREDIT,2885216217,mircy@gmail.com
2021-03-02,DEPOSIT,Aaren,SAVINGS,19335
2021-03-03,DEPOSIT,Aarika,SAVINGS,3108
2021-03-04,DEPOSIT,Abagael,SAVINGS,1687
2021-03-05,DEPOSIT,Abagail,SAVINGS,3271
2021-03-06,DEPOSIT,Abbe,SAVINGS,3417
2021-03-07,DEPOSIT,Abbey,SAVINGS,6948
2021-03-08,DEPOSIT,Abbi,SAVINGS,16017
2021-03-09,DEPOSIT,Abbie,SAVINGS,16159
2021-03-10,DEPOSIT,Abby,SAVINGS,17934
2021-03-11,DEPOSIT,Abbye,SAVINGS,13351
2021-03-12,DEPOSIT,Abigael,SAVINGS,15257
2021-03-13,DEPOSIT,Abigail,SAVINGS,15906
2021-03-14,DEPOSIT,Abigale,SAVINGS,7966
2021-03-15,DEPOSIT,Abra,SAVINGS,17697
2021-03-16,DEPOSIT,Ada,SAVINGS,10373
2021-03-17,DEPOSIT,Adah,SAVINGS,11706
2021-03-18,DEPOSIT,Adaline,SAVINGS,2951
2021-03-19,DEPOSIT,Adan,SAVINGS,5095
2021-03-20,DEPOSIT,Adara,SAVINGS,8557
2021-03-21,DEPOSIT,Adda,SAVINGS,7239
2021-03-22,DEPOSIT,Addi,SAVINGS,15647
2021-03-23,DEPOSIT,Addia,SAVINGS,15566
2021-03-24,DEPOSIT,Addie,SAVINGS,14290
2021-03-25,DEPOSIT,Addy,SAVINGS,9788
2021-03-26,DEPOSIT,Adel,SAVINGS,12714
2021-03-27,DEPOSIT,Adela,SAVINGS,13344
2021-03-28,DEPOSIT,Adelaida,SAVINGS,14842
2021-03-29,DEPOSIT,Adelaide,SAVINGS,8306
2021-03-30,DEPOSIT,Adele,SAVINGS,12760
2021-03-31,DEPOSIT,Adelheid,SAVINGS,1665
2021-04-01,DEPOSIT,Adelice,SAVINGS,3350
2021-04-02,DEPOSIT,Adelina,SAVINGS,10723
2021-04-03,DEPOSIT,Adelind,SAVINGS,3981
2021-04-04,DEPOSIT,Adeline,SAVINGS,8791
2021-04-05,DEPOSIT,Adella,SAVINGS,13782
2021-04-06,DEPOSIT,Adelle,SAVINGS,11571
2021-04-07,DEPOSIT,Adena,SAVINGS,2089
2021-04-08,DEPOSIT,Adey,SAVINGS,17985
2021-04-09,DEPOSIT,Adi,SAVINGS,9088
2021-04-10,DEPOSIT,Adiana,SAVINGS,2732
2021-04-11,DEPOSIT,Adina,SAVINGS,7206
2021-04-12,DEPOSIT,Adora,SAVINGS,1554
2021-04-13,DEPOSIT,Adore,SAVINGS,10953
2021-04-14,DEPOSIT,Adoree,SAVINGS,5262
2021-04-15,DEPOSIT,Adorne,SAVINGS,12557
2021-04-16,DEPOSIT,Adrea,SAVINGS,13032
2021-04-17,DEPOSIT,Adria,SAVINGS,18403
2021-04-18,DEPOSIT,Adriaens,SAVINGS,9416
2021-04-19,DEPOSIT,Adrian,SAVINGS,5055
2021-04-20,DEPOSIT,Adriana,SAVINGS,9035
2021-04-21,DEPOSIT,Adriane,SAVINGS,19005
2021-04-22,DEPOSIT,Adrianna,SAVINGS,14933
2021-04-23,DEPOSIT,Adrianne,SAVINGS,17694
2021-04-24,DEPOSIT,Adriena,SAVINGS,17252
2021-04-25,DEPOSIT,Adrienne,SAVINGS,5694
2021-04-26,DEPOSIT,Aeriel,SAVINGS,14377
2021-04-27,DEPOSIT,Aeriela,SAVINGS,16095
2021-04-28,DEPOSIT,Aeriell,SAVINGS,14529
2021-04-29,DEPOSIT,Afton,SAVINGS,7388
2021-04-30,DEPOSIT,Ag,SAVINGS,14221
2021-05-01,DEPOSIT,Agace,SAVINGS,4119
2021-05-02,DEPOSIT,Agata,SAVINGS,10840
2021-05-03,DEPOSIT,Agatha,SAVINGS,19716
2021-05-04,DEPOSIT,Agathe,SAVINGS,11626
2021-05-05,DEPOSIT,Aggi,SAVINGS,7368
2021-05-06,DEPOSIT,Aggie,SAVINGS,18910
2021-05-07,DEPOSIT,Aggy,SAVINGS,12174
2021-05-08,DEPOSIT,Agna,SAVINGS,12081
2021-05-09,DEPOSIT,Agnella,SAVINGS,6660
2021-05-10,DEPOSIT,Agnes,SAVINGS,18544
2021-05-11,DEPOSIT,Agnese,SAVINGS,4825
2021-05-12,DEPOSIT,Agnesse,SAVINGS,11709
2021-05-13,DEPOSIT,Agneta,SAVINGS,18805
2021-05-14,DEPOSIT,Agnola,SAVINGS,10320
2021-05-15,DEPOSIT,Agretha,SAVINGS,7874
2021-05-16,DEPOSIT,Aida,CHECKING,15818
2021-05-17,DEPOSIT,Aidan,CHECKING,17285
2021-05-18,DEPOSIT,Aigneis,CHECKING,17192
2021-05-19,DEPOSIT,Aila,CHECKING,2280
2021-05-20,DEPOSIT,Aile,CHECKING,16974
2021-05-21,DEPOSIT,Ailee,CHECKING,2623
2021-05-22,DEPOSIT,Aileen,CHECKING,2285
2021-05-23,DEPOSIT,Ailene,CHECKING,10085
2021-05-24,DEPOSIT,Ailey,CHECKING,6294
2021-05-25,DEPOSIT,Aili,CHECKING,17484
2021-05-26,DEPOSIT,Ailina,CHECKING,19566
2021-05-27,DEPOSIT,Ailis,CHECKING,17562
2021-05-28,DEPOSIT,Ailsun,CHECKING,11767
2021-05-29,DEPOSIT,Ailyn,CHECKING,16951
2021-05-30,DEPOSIT,Aime,CHECKING,1216
2021-05-31,DEPOSIT,Aimee,CHECKING,17655
2021-06-01,DEPOSIT,Aimil,CHECKING,17832
2021-06-02,DEPOSIT,Aindrea,CHECKING,16325
2021-06-03,DEPOSIT,Ainslee,CHECKING,4929
2021-06-04,DEPOSIT,Ainsley,CHECKING,9332
2021-06-05,DEPOSIT,Ainslie,CHECKING,13964
2021-06-06,DEPOSIT,Ajay,CHECKING,13682
2021-06-07,DEPOSIT,Alaine,CHECKING,13099
2021-06-08,DEPOSIT,Alameda,CHECKING,3301
2021-06-09,DEPOSIT,Alana,CHECKING,18817
2021-06-10,DEPOSIT,Alanah,CHECKING,5520
2021-06-11,DEPOSIT,Alane,CHECKING,13950
2021-06-12,DEPOSIT,Alanna,CHECKING,8353
2021-06-13,DEPOSIT,Alayne,CHECKING,9637
2021-06-14,DEPOSIT,Alberta,CHECKING,1378
2021-06-15,DEPOSIT,Albertina,CHECKING,5371
2021-06-16,DEPOSIT,Albertine,CHECKING,14080
2021-06-17,DEPOSIT,Albina,CHECKING,19344
2021-06-18,DEPOSIT,Alecia,CHECKING,9502
2021-06-19,DEPOSIT,Aleda,CHECKING,3383
2021-06-20,DEPOSIT,Aleece,CHECKING,2128
2021-06-21,DEPOSIT,Aleen,CHECKING,14147
2021-06-22,DEPOSIT,Alejandra,CHECKING,12017
2021-06-23,DEPOSIT,Alejandrina,CHECKING,9988
2021-06-24,DEPOSIT,Alena,CHECKING,19035
2021-06-25,DEPOSIT,Alene,CHECKING,10540
2021-06-26,DEPOSIT,Alessandra,CHECKING,19182
2021-06-27,DEPOSIT,Aleta,CHECKING,4493
2021-06-28,DEPOSIT,Alethea,CHECKING,2024
2021-06-29,DEPOSIT,Alex,CHECKING,9848
2021-06-30,DEPOSIT,Alexa,CHECKING,19687
2021-07-01,DEPOSIT,Alexandra,CHECKING,12534
2021-07-02,DEPOSIT,Alexandrina,CHECKING,17902
2021-07-03,DEPOSIT,Alexi,CHECKING,8450
2021-07-04,DEPOSIT,Alexia,CHECKING,12682
2021-07-05,DEPOSIT,Alexina,CHECKING,12299
2021-07-06,DEPOSIT,Alexine,CHECKING,7392
2021-07-07,DEPOSIT,Alexis,CHECKING,16241
2021-07-08,DEPOSIT,Alfi,CHECKING,5660
2021-07-09,DEPOSIT,Alfie,CHECKING,4731
2021-07-10,DEPOSIT,Alfreda,CHECKING,10690
2021-07-11,DEPOSIT,Alfy,CHECKING,16152
2021-07-12,DEPOSIT,Ali,CHECKING,6464
2021-07-13,DEPOSIT,Alia,CHECKING,18585
2021-07-14,DEPOSIT,Alica,CHECKING,19391
2021-07-15,DEPOSIT,Alice,CHECKING,9182
2021-07-16,DEPOSIT,Alicea,CHECKING,18064
2021-07-17,DEPOSIT,Alicia,CHECKING,5761
2021-07-18,DEPOSIT,Alida,CHECKING,12152
2021-07-19,DEPOSIT,Alidia,CHECKING,4887
2021-07-20,DEPOSIT,Alie,CHECKING,13049
2021-07-21,DEPOSIT,Alika,CHECKING,10548
2021-07-22,DEPOSIT,Alikee,CHECKING,18296
2021-07-23,DEPOSIT,Alina,CHECKING,15318
2021-07-24,DEPOSIT,Aline,CHECKING,2172
2021-07-25,DEPOSIT,Alis,CHECKING,11632
2021-07-26,DEPOSIT,Alisa,CHECKING,2071
2021-07-27,DEPOSIT,Alisha,CHECKING,15797
2021-07-28,DEPOSIT,Alison,CHECKING,7270
2021-07-29,DEPOSIT,Alissa,CHECKING,14567
2021-07-30,DEPOSIT,Alisun,CREDIT,17407
2021-07-31,DEPOSIT,Alix,CREDIT,18222
2021-08-01,DEPOSIT,Aliza,CREDIT,9154
2021-08-02,DEPOSIT,Alla,CREDIT,7513
2021-08-03,DEPOSIT,Alleen,CREDIT,11823
2021-08-04,DEPOSIT,Allegra,CREDIT,12257
2021-08-05,DEPOSIT,Allene,CREDIT,7202
2021-08-06,DEPOSIT,Alli,CREDIT,11781
2021-08-07,DEPOSIT,Allianora,CREDIT,8060
2021-08-08,DEPOSIT,Allie,CREDIT,16991
2021-08-09,DEPOSIT,Allina,CREDIT,19889
2021-08-10,DEPOSIT,Allis,CREDIT,2888
2021-08-11,DEPOSIT,Allison,CREDIT,7653
2021-08-12,DEPOSIT,Allissa,CREDIT,4769
2021-08-13,DEPOSIT,Allix,CREDIT,18664
2021-08-14,DEPOSIT,Allsun,CREDIT,6121
2021-08-15,DEPOSIT,Allx,CREDIT,19110
2021-08-16,DEPOSIT,Ally,CREDIT,16231
2021-08-17,DEPOSIT,Allyce,CREDIT,4267
2021-08-18,DEPOSIT,Allyn,CREDIT,15771
2021-08-19,DEPOSIT,Allys,CREDIT,15044
2021-08-20,DEPOSIT,Allyson,CREDIT,4015
2021-08-21,DEPOSIT,Alma,CREDIT,1966
2021-08-22,DEPOSIT,Almeda,CREDIT,17688
2021-08-23,DEPOSIT,Almeria,CREDIT,4271
2021-08-24,DEPOSIT,Almeta,CREDIT,10453
2021-08-25,DEPOSIT,Almira,CREDIT,19140
2021-08-26,DEPOSIT,Almire,CREDIT,17347
2021-08-27,DEPOSIT,Aloise,CREDIT,11584
2021-08-28,DEPOSIT,Aloisia,CREDIT,6650
2021-08-29,DEPOSIT,Aloysia,CREDIT,13837
2021-08-30,DEPOSIT,Alta,CREDIT,2672
2021-08-31,DEPOSIT,Althea,CREDIT,18679
2021-09-01,DEPOSIT,Alvera,CREDIT,13265
2021-09-02,DEPOSIT,Alverta,CREDIT,3133
2021-09-03,DEPOSIT,Alvina,CREDIT,6704
2021-09-04,DEPOSIT,Alvinia,CREDIT,16397
2021-09-05,DEPOSIT,Alvira,CREDIT,1910
2021-09-06,DEPOSIT,Alyce,CREDIT,12995
2021-09-07,DEPOSIT,Alyda,CREDIT,7110
2021-09-08,DEPOSIT,Alys,CREDIT,10264
2021-09-09,DEPOSIT,Alysa,CREDIT,16723
2021-09-10,DEPOSIT,Alyse,CREDIT,9859
2021-09-11,DEPOSIT,Alysia,CREDIT,2708
2021-09-12,DEPOSIT,Alyson,CREDIT,7852
2021-09-13,DEPOSIT,Alyss,CREDIT,6705
2021-09-14,DEPOSIT,Alyssa,CREDIT,19630
2021-09-15,DEPOSIT,Amabel,CREDIT,19180
2021-09-16,DEPOSIT,Amabelle,CREDIT,13240
2021-09-17,DEPOSIT,Amalea,CREDIT,18789
2021-09-18,DEPOSIT,Amalee,CREDIT,16633
2021-09-19,DEPOSIT,Amaleta,CREDIT,4517
2021-09-20,DEPOSIT,Amalia,CREDIT,5205
2021-09-21,DEPOSIT,Amalie,CREDIT,5956
2021-09-22,DEPOSIT,Amalita,CREDIT,19029
2021-09-23,DEPOSIT,Amalle,CREDIT,12375
2021-09-24,DEPOSIT,Amanda,CREDIT,8930
2021-09-25,DEPOSIT,Amandi,CREDIT,14441
2021-09-26,DEPOSIT,Amandie,CREDIT,5117
2021-09-27,DEPOSIT,Amandy,CREDIT,9053
2021-09-28,DEPOSIT,Amara,CREDIT,9639
2021-09-29,DEPOSIT,Amargo,CREDIT,2007
2021-09-30,DEPOSIT,Amata,CREDIT,12854
2021-10-01,DEPOSIT,Amber,CREDIT,16225
2021-10-02,DEPOSIT,Amberly,CREDIT,17853
2021-10-03,DEPOSIT,Ambur,CREDIT,13296
2021-10-04,DEPOSIT,Ame,CREDIT,11881
2021-10-05,DEPOSIT,Amelia,CREDIT,5683
2021-10-06,DEPOSIT,Amelie,CREDIT,16465
2021-10-07,DEPOSIT,Amelina,CREDIT,17278
2021-10-08,DEPOSIT,Ameline,CREDIT,2469
2021-10-09,DEPOSIT,Amelita,CREDIT,1307
2021-10-10,DEPOSIT,Ami,CREDIT,17483
2021-10-11,DEPOSIT,Amie,CREDIT,14868
2021-10-12,DEPOSIT,Amii,CREDIT,6811
2021-10-13,WITHDRAW,Aaren,SAVINGS,993
2021-10-14,WITHDRAW,Aarika,SAVINGS,228
2021-10-15,WITHDRAW,Abagael,SAVINGS,229
2021-10-16,WITHDRAW,Abagail,SAVINGS,508
2021-10-17,WITHDRAW,Abbe,SAVINGS,646
2021-10-18,WITHDRAW,Abbey,SAVINGS,240
2021-10-19,WITHDRAW,Abbi,SAVINGS,156
2021-10-20,WITHDRAW,Abbie,SAVINGS,963
2021-10-21,WITHDRAW,Abby,SAVINGS,122
2021-10-22,WITHDRAW,Abbye,SAVINGS,823
2021-10-23,WITHDRAW,Abigael,SAVINGS,221
2021-10-24,WITHDRAW,Abigail,SAVINGS,523
2021-10-25,WITHDRAW,Abigale,SAVINGS,482
2021-10-26,WITHDRAW,Abra,SAVINGS,586
2021-10-27,WITHDRAW,Ada,SAVINGS,810
2021-10-28,WITHDRAW,Adah,SAVINGS,517
2021-10-29,WITHDRAW,Adaline,SAVINGS,913
2021-10-30,WITHDRAW,Adan,SAVINGS,833
2021-10-31,WITHDRAW,Adara,SAVINGS,899
2021-11-01,WITHDRAW,Adda,SAVINGS,615
2021-11-02,WITHDRAW,Addi,SAVINGS,813
2021-11-03,WITHDRAW,Addia,SAVINGS,612
2021-11-04,WITHDRAW,Addie,SAVINGS,857
2021-11-05,WITHDRAW,Addy,SAVINGS,988
2021-11-06,WITHDRAW,Adel,SAVINGS,747
2021-11-07,WITHDRAW,Adela,SAVINGS,643
2021-11-08,WITHDRAW,Adelaida,SAVINGS,413
2021-11-09,WITHDRAW,Adelaide,SAVINGS,939
2021-11-10,WITHDRAW,Adele,SAVINGS,114
2021-11-11,WITHDRAW,Adelheid,SAVINGS,618
2021-11-12,WITHDRAW,Adelice,SAVINGS,387
2021-11-13,WITHDRAW,Adelina,SAVINGS,735
2021-11-14,WITHDRAW,Adelind,SAVINGS,314
2021-11-15,WITHDRAW,Adeline,SAVINGS,651
2021-11-16,WITHDRAW,Adella,SAVINGS,824
2021-11-17,WITHDRAW,Adelle,SAVINGS,575
2021-11-18,WITHDRAW,Adena,SAVINGS,886
2021-11-19,WITHDRAW,Adey,SAVINGS,944
2021-11-20,WITHDRAW,Adi,SAVINGS,819
2021-11-21,WITHDRAW,Adiana,SAVINGS,618
2021-11-22,WITHDRAW,Adina,SAVINGS,389
2021-11-23,WITHDRAW,Adora,SAVINGS,496
2021-11-24,WITHDRAW,Adore,SAVINGS,701
2021-11-25,WITHDRAW,Adoree,SAVINGS,677
2021-11-26,WITHDRAW,Adorne,SAVINGS,369
2021-11-27,WITHDRAW,Adrea,SAVINGS,890
2021-11-28,WITHDRAW,Adria,SAVINGS,631
2021-11-29,WITHDRAW,Adriaens,SAVINGS,236
2021-11-30,WITHDRAW,Adrian,SAVINGS,378
2021-12-01,WITHDRAW,Adriana,SAVINGS,717
2021-12-02,WITHDRAW,Adriane,SAVINGS,320
2021-12-03,WITHDRAW,Adrianna,SAVINGS,112
2021-12-04,WITHDRAW,Adrianne,SAVINGS,363
2021-12-05,WITHDRAW,Adriena,SAVINGS,763
2021-12-06,WITHDRAW,Adrienne,SAVINGS,277
2021-12-07,WITHDRAW,Aeriel,SAVINGS,268
2021-12-08,WITHDRAW,Aeriela,SAVINGS,249
2021-12-09,WITHDRAW,Aeriell,SAVINGS,188
2021-12-10,WITHDRAW,Afton,SAVINGS,688
2021-12-11,WITHDRAW,Ag,SAVINGS,724
2021-12-12,WITHDRAW,Agace,SAVINGS,135
2021-12-13,WITHDRAW,Agata,SAVINGS,524
2021-12-14,WITHDRAW,Agatha,SAVINGS,828
2021-12-15,WITHDRAW,Agathe,SAVINGS,452
2021-12-16,WITHDRAW,Aggi,SAVINGS,480
2021-12-17,WITHDRAW,Aggie,SAVINGS,921
2021-12-18,WITHDRAW,Aggy,SAVINGS,743
```

Comment: At which line do you get the error?

Comment: @Andrej line 9, first ```accountinfo[name]["name"] = name``` command line in StoreInfo

Comment: check how classes work. Currently you're using them as namespaces, and the methods are static. This isn't good practice

Comment: Try adding ```accountinfo = {}``` before that line.

Comment: @Andrej now I'm getting ```KeyError: 'Aaren'``` (Aaren is the first name from the text file), error is on the same line

Comment: `accountinfo = {}` then later `class accountinfo:` these are overriding each other, don't name them the same thing. Also `p+=1` won't work without a `global` statement, also `accountinfo[name]` is never initialized so trying to set a property of it fails (the key error you just got) and `while i < sum(1 for line in open('textfile.txt')):` opens and reads the entire file every loop.... There are quite a few issues with the file here.

Comment: Try to put this into your apply function. ```accountinfo = {"name": {"name":"Aaren", "email":"aaren@example.com", "number": 12345, "type": "business", "balance": 0}}```

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen From what I've seen, doing ```dictionary_name["new_dict"]["new_key] = "value"``` *should* create a new dictionary, value, and key inside of dictionary_name as long as they don't already exist, so I don't know why it's trying to find that value inside of the dictionary instead of creating it. As for as the while statement, I can set ```sum(1 for line in open('textfile.txt'))``` equal to a variable so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Andrej that fixed it but now it presents the same error for the next name in the file (Aarika)

Comment: Can you send us the files content?

Comment: @Andrej I edited it in, I could only include about half because of character limit, after a few more WITHDRAW commands it would include 225 BAL-INQUERY commands and then 225 ACCOUNT-INFO commands

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If you're saying that I should delete the classes and only use ```def function()```, my teacher is unfortunately requiring me to use classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use a global dictionary as your class fields.

Consider using proper class definitions as follows

```py
class StoreInfo:
    def __init__(self, name, email, number, type):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.number = number
        self.type = type

...
stores = []
...
with open('textfile') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        ...
        stores.apppend(StoreInfo(name, email, number, type))
```

[Python classes tutorial](http://%5BPython%20Classes%5D%5Bhttps://www.learnpython.org/en/Classes_and_Objects%5D)

Comment: Wouldn't this simply store all of my info inside of a list? I've already used lists in a previous version of this program and I'm trying to do it with nested dictionaries this time.

Comment: Nevermind! I kept my dictionaries but added ```def __init__()``` stuff and it seems to have removed the errors, I'm running into some other ones but we'll see where this goes - EDIT: All the errors disappeared, thank you!!